# GCM: How do you subscribe a device to a topic?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

An Android app/device can call PubSub subscribe() to subscribe to a topic.

Is it possible to subscribe and unsubscribe a device with its registration id to a topic using GCM's HTTP API? An example or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible, there is no way to subscribe a device to Topics from server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:**
Yes, as @Asaf mentioned, you can do that via this an API call:
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME

Here is the [doc](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance)

> Given a registration token and a supported relationship, you can
>   create a mapping. For example, you can subscribe an app instance to a
>   Google Cloud Messaging topic by calling the Instance ID service at
>   this endpoint, providing the app instance's token as shown:
>
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME
>
> **Parameters**
>
> Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY. Set this parameter in the header.

Comment: Not sure that's true. Did you take a look on this? https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance